# Making multiple contrast from a list

Tags: r

I have different condition to test which are as such

```
coldata$FAB
  [1] M4 M0 M4 M2 M1 M3 M5 M1 M0 M5 M4 M0 M4 M0 M4 M5 M2 M4 M1 M4 M2 M2 M2 M0 M2 M0 M0 M0 M5 M3 M1 M4 M3 M2 M1 M2 M1 M2 M2 M0 M4 M1 M1 M2 M1 M4 M3
 [48] M5 M4 M2 M0 M2 M4 M4 M2 M4 M1 M1 M0 M4 M1 M1 M2 M1 M4 M3 M3 M5 M2 M2 M4 M1 M1 M1 M2 M4 M1 M2 M5 M0 M1 M2 M1 M2 M2 M5 M1 M1 M4 M2 M2 M2 M1 M4
 [95] M1 M3 M0 M5 M5 M2 M2 M4 M5 M1 M0 M4 M1 M3 M4 M1 M5 M5 M2 M3 M4 M2 M1 M3 M5 M1 M4 M3 M1 M3 M4 M2 M2 M2 M2 M4 M1 M1 M2 M0 M2 M2 M1 M1 M5 M3 M1
[142] M3 M3 M2 M1 M4 M4
Levels: M0 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5
```

These are my different sub-types.

> M0 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5

To generate a multiple contrast

I got a function like this

```
unique_combn <- combn(c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4" ,"M5"), 2)
unique_combn
contrasts <- lapply(1:ncol(unique_combn), function(x){
  
  c("FAB", unique_combn[1,x], unique_combn[2,x])
  
})
names(contrasts) <- unlist(lapply(contrasts, function(x) paste(x[2], x[3], sep = "_vs_")))

contrasts

names(contrasts) <- unlist(lapply(contrasts, function(x) paste(x[2], x[3], sep = "_vs_")))

contrasts
```

The contrasts is generated as such

```
contrasts
$M0_vs_M1
[1] "FAB" "M0"  "M1" 

$M0_vs_M2
[1] "FAB" "M0"  "M2" 

$M0_vs_M3
[1] "FAB" "M0"  "M3" 

$M0_vs_M4
[1] "FAB" "M0"  "M4" 

$M0_vs_M5
[1] "FAB" "M0"  "M5" 

$M1_vs_M2
[1] "FAB" "M1"  "M2" 

$M1_vs_M3
[1] "FAB" "M1"  "M3" 

$M1_vs_M4
[1] "FAB" "M1"  "M4" 

$M1_vs_M5
[1] "FAB" "M1"  "M5" 

$M2_vs_M3
[1] "FAB" "M2"  "M3" 

$M2_vs_M4
[1] "FAB" "M2"  "M4" 

$M2_vs_M5
[1] "FAB" "M2"  "M5" 

$M3_vs_M4
[1] "FAB" "M3"  "M4" 

$M3_vs_M5
[1] "FAB" "M3"  "M5" 

$M4_vs_M5
[1] "FAB" "M4"  "M5"
```

Where each of them are my all possible combinations.

So now I would like to pass the list either one by one which is doable if the list is small but I have more samples as well to compare.

For example I want to compare the first condition I use this code below to get my desired output.

```
M0_vs_M1 <- results(dds, contrast=contrasts[["M0_vs_M1"]])
```

This generates my desired output.

Now I would like to do the same for other generated contrasts and then save those output into different tables.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

**UPDATE**

My dds object

```
head(dds)
class: DESeqDataSet 
dim: 6 147 
metadata(1): version
assays(6): counts mu ... replaceCounts replaceCooks
rownames(6): ENSG00000223972 ENSG00000227232 ... ENSG00000237613 ENSG00000268020
rowData names(39): baseMean baseVar ... maxCooks replace
colnames(147): TCGA-AB-2856 TCGA-AB-2849 ... TCGA-AB-2970 TCGA-AB-2933
colData names(3): FAB sizeFactor replaceable
```

Since my dds object I can't show because I'm not sure if i can put that in a dataframe kind of.Here is a dummy data to show the dds

```
dds <- makeExampleDESeqDataSet(n = 1000, m = 12, betaSD = 2)
dds$colour <- factor(rep(c("pink", "white"), each = 6))
dds$colour <- relevel(dds$colour, "white")
dds$condition <- factor(rep(c("sun", "shade"), 6))
dds <- dds[, order(dds$colour, dds$condition)]
colnames(dds) <- paste0("sample", 1:ncol(dds))


design(dds) <- ~ 1 + colour + condition + colour:condition
dds <- DESeq(dds)
resultsNames(dds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use lapply again

`results <- lapply(contrasts, function(x) results(dds, contrast=x))`

Answer (score 2):

**not an answer** ;-), *but too long for a comment*

I see no sample data of `dds`, so using `lapply()` is the best generic answer I can give...

There are some improvements in your code to create `contrasts` that I would like to hand to you.

```
# make smart use of the possible arguments from the combn-function
contrasts <- combn( c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4" ,"M5"), 
                    FUN = function(x) c("FAB", x),
                    m = 2, 
                    simplify = FALSE)


names(contrasts) <- sapply(
  combn( c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4" ,"M5"), m = 2, simplify = FALSE),
  paste0, collapse = "_vs_")

# $M0_vs_M1
# [1] "FAB" "M0"  "M1" 
# 
# $M0_vs_M2
# [1] "FAB" "M0"  "M2" 
# 
# $M0_vs_M3
# [1] "FAB" "M0"  "M3" 
# 
# $M0_vs_M4
# [1] "FAB" "M0"  "M4" 
# 
# $M0_vs_M5
# [1] "FAB" "M0"  "M5" 
#
# ......
```

Comment: I have updated my question with sample dds i will try what you have given

Comment: "contrasts that I would like to hand to you." thank you one more ways to keep the code clean .